# Styling / coloring the SwitchCompat button in Android Lollipop for Material Design

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-switch

I have been trying to find resources explaining how I can style the `Switch` button in the Material Design theme.

This link does explain the color values and aesthetic details but doesn't say much on how I can achieve this by setting certain attributes in Material design theme.

> http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/switches.html#switches-switch

If there's no direct way of setting the Switch's color, where are the drawables located that I can use to make my own version?

Comment: yeah there is no direct way to change. You need to create drawables if you want to modify styles of switches, buttons etc...

Comment: @MurtazaHussain And do you know where I could find the drawables used by Lollipop?

Comment: Are you trying to modify the style for API 21+, or do you need it to work with appcompat?

Comment: @alanv I am using appcompat-v7 21.0

Comment: @FoY The link is not working now

Answer (score 17):

> I have been trying to find resources explaining as to how I can style switch button in the Material Design theme.

Coloring widgets is pretty simple now with the new appcompat-v7:21.

As long as you are using appcompat-v7:21, you can replace all of your old `Switch` widgets with `SwitchCompat` widgets. So in your xml layouts, instead of using the old `Switch` tag, use `android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat`.

Then in your styles.xml, make sure your app's parent theme is a `Theme.AppCompat` theme such as `Theme.AppCompat.Light`.

Finally, the key is to specify your own value for `colorAccent`:

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/my_fancy_color</item>
```

**The color you specify for `colorAccent` will be used to color the widgets in your app such as `SwitchCompats`, `EditTexts`, `RadioButtons`, etc.**

So your styles.xml might look something like:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>

    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used to color the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>

    <!-- 
         colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to color widgets 
    -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/my_fancy_color</item>

    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight & colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
</style>
```

> where are the drawables located that I can use to make my own version?

I wouldn't recommend altering the drawables directly, but they are located in

`sdk/platforms/android-21/data/res/drawable-XXXX`

and the files are called

btn_switch_to_off_mtrl_XXXXX.9.png

btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_XXXXX.9.png

switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png

Comment: I have already tried this. On some devices SwitchCompat simply disappears. I think it's some bug, probably the same as what Anthone mentioned. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 6):

To complete JDJ's answer:

There is a bug with a corrupt file in drawable-hdpi in AppCompat:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78262

To fix it, just override it with these 2 files:

https://github.com/lopespm/quick-fix-switchcompat-resources

Add them to your drawable-hdpi directory.

XML

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
android:id="@+id/dev_switch_show_dev_only"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

And nothing was necessary in Java

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I only wanted to style a particular switch, not all of them in the app. Here is how I did that using AppCompat-v7:23

xml layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
                android:id="@+id/switchAffiliateMember"
                android:theme="@style/Sugar.Switch.Affiliate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:textOff="No"
                android:textOn="Yes" />
```

v21/styles.xml:

```
<style name="Sugar.Switch.Affiliate" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.Switch">
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/red</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

colorSwitchThumbNormal is the "off" state, colorAccent is the "on" state. Notice that neither of these have an "android" namespace prefix, I don't understand why, but it only works in this way for me.

Comment: `colorSwitchThumbNormal` doesn't do anything for me (Lollipop stock ROM)